# How can I specify the type of a bit string through a variable

Tags: erlang

Erlang doesn't let me do:

```
Type = bitstring. 
<<FirstPart:8/Type, Rest/bitstring>> = some_binary.
```

although it lets me do:

```
Size = 8. 
<<FirstPart:Size/bitstring, Rest/bitstring>> = some_binary.
```

So, in bit string expressions, while I can pass the size through a variable, It doesnt let me pass the type through a variable. Is there any solution?

Comment: 500th question tagged 'Erlang' :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a case statement as a workaround:

```
{FirstPart, Rest} = case Type of
                        {'bitstring', Len} ->
                            <<A:Len/bitstring, B/bitstring>> = Bin,
                            {A,B};
                        'integer' ->
                            <<A/integer, B/bitstring>> = Bin,
                            {A,B};
                        ...
```

Comment: This works for me, and i already have done it like this. I was just wondring why they havent made it possible to use a var for the type...

Comment: My _guess_ is that the binary expressions are compiled into something internal at compilation time.

Comment: is right, binary expressions are compiled and not having the type would make it slow.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything extraordinary here that makes a conditional inconvenient for handling the different "types" of encoding.

```
case StringType of
  byte_len ->
    <<Len:8, String:Len/binary>> = SomeBinary,
    String;
  word_len ->
    <<Len:32, String:Len/binary>> = SomeBinary,
    String;
  etc -> ...
end
```